# How do I resolve this error; 'document.getElementById('myChart').getContext' is undefined)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, chart.js

I have tried looking at related answered problems regarding the error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById('myChart').getContext is not a function. (In 'document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d')', 'document.getElementById('myChart').getContext' is undefined)
```

but no suggestions have come through for me thus far. I'm trying to work with chart.js library and keep getting the error in the title. Below are my HTML and javascript codes, the js code is in a separate file called app.js Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  
    <title></title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="contxt.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id='myChart'></div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

And here is the JS:

```
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fire)
}else{
    fire()
}

function fire() {

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have an element with ID `canvas` anywhere. Or even a `<canvas>` tag which you'd need to get with `document.querySelector("canvas")`

Comment: OK...completely new error now which does make a lot more sense: [`getContext()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) is a method on a canvas element, not a div.

Comment: Also, even though it's just a convention, _always use double quotes_ in the HTML

Comment: @Nico No reason to. It can certainly be part of a style guide but I'm not sure there is a good reason to *always* use double quotes. Unless you plan on using a lot of single quotes in the values, I guess. But other than that, the quotes are pretty much interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

Only a canvas can have a context. Please change

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='myChart'></div>
</div>
```

for

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas> <!-- this line -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ Nico :)...it works perfectly now. Thanks